# Xcode: detect identifier row selected

Tags: xcode, segue, didselectrowatindexpath

My project contains two designs for cell in a uitableview and show it correctly, but the problem is when I select a row for pass to detailsviewcontroller with a segue...

How can I detect the identifier of the selected row?
Depends on the selected row... In didselectrowatindexpath needs redirect to other detailsviewcontroller.

Thanks for all ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to the selected cell, you have access to it's ["`reuseIdentifier`"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/reuseIdentifier) (the documentation for which I've linked for you here).

Comment: Please, show me an example for didSelectRowAtIndexPath type: if(cell.identifier == 'Cell1'){}else{}...

Comment: how about "`if([cell.reuseIdentifier isEqualTo: @"Cell1"])`"?